# Insert div into an exact cell of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to insert the div

```
<div class="inner">
  <p>The 1st paragraph</p>
  <p>The 2nd paragraph</p>
</div>
```

into an exact cell of the table?

Both plain JS or jQuery will be fine, athough plain JS will be a bit better.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>
      <!-- ........ point to insert ........ -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { padding: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: You have to somehow mark the TD you want to insert the div into.

Comment: Or you can decide you want the DIV inside the 2nd cell in the table, so you can just count them...

Comment: When you speak of wrapping, does that mean that all the other content of that wrapping table is non-dynamic, and always the same? Or do you want to have multiple divs wrapped by 1 common table, in which they all will appear?

Comment: @trincot Yes, you are right!

Comment: It was an "or" question. Which is right?

Comment: Do you have the "template" table as a DOM object, or just as HTML string? Same question for the div.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I was emotional. Your first option was right. It will be some HTML document with content like: ..... table ..... table ..... table ..... table. The tables will be identical, except the `inner` divs inside them. Hope it's clear.

Comment: So at the start, do you have the table as HTML string, or as object, or is it on the current page? Same question for the DIV. Do you have it as HTML string, or as object, or is it on the current page?

Comment: It will be static page. Divs will be created manually and so, they are located just on that page. About table, I honestly doesn't understand. I'm not professional in JS.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not clear to me. You want to modify the page the JS is running on. Do you want to **add** a table, or do you want to modify a table that is already on the page? Do you want to **move** or **copy** a div that is already on the page inside that table? ... So many things are unclear. Why don't you give a more concrete example from start to finish. Describe what the page is before you do anything, where you get your input from and the end result.

Comment: Oh... Is it really not clear? You can use jQuery `wrap` to wrap some div with another. I just want to use table as a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert in the second td of the table, you can try this

```
var d='<div class="inner"><p>The 1st paragraph</p><p>The 2nd paragraph</p></div>';
$("table td").eq(1).html(d);
```

Or if you have an id set to your specific td, you can use that as your jQuery selector

```
<td id="myEmpty"></td>
```

and your jQuery code  will be

```
$("#myEmpty").html(d);
```

Or if you want to move your markup from your DOM  to this cell,

```
var d=$('div.inner');
$('div.inner').remove();
$("table td").eq(1).html(d);
```

It might be a good idea to give an id to your div and use that as your jQuery selector instead of using the class name selector ( because you can have more than one item with same css class)

Answer (score 0):

You can selected last `td` of first `tr` using `table tr:first td:last` selector and add your `html` to it like following.

```js
$('table tr:first td:last').html('<div class="inner"><p>The 1st paragraph</p><p>The 2nd paragraph</p></div>')
```

```css
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>
      <!-- ........ point to insert ........ -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inner').detach().appendTo('table tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)');
});
```

```css
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
  <p>The 1st paragraph</p>
  <p>The 2nd paragraph</p>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>
      <!-- ........ point to insert ........ -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Javascript implementation.

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
cells[1].innerHTML = '<div class="inner"><p>The 1st paragraph</p><p>The 2nd paragraph</p></div>';
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>
      <!-- ........ point to insert ........ -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { padding: 0; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would mark the element with id, then use getElementById("thatId").innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution, that also does not inject HTML, but works purely with the DOM methods:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'inner');

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The 1st paragraph'));
div.appendChild(p);

p = document.createElement('p');
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The 2nd paragraph'));
div.appendChild(p);

var table = document.querySelector('table');
table.rows[0].cells[1].appendChild(div);
```

```css
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { padding: 0; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>
      <!-- ........ point to insert ........ -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
    <td>Just an empty cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```